# Is the sum between a norm and a seminorm still a norm?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, normed-spaces

Let $X$ denote a vector space. Let $n:X\to\mathbb R$ be a norm over $X$ and let $s:X\to\mathbb R$ be a seminorm over $X$.

I have proved quite easily that the sum of two norms is a norm itself. I would like to understand what happens if I sum a norm with a seminorm.

Does one obtain a norm or a seminorm?

According to me the result is a norm, but I heard some classmates that proved that the result of the sum is a seminorm instead.

Anyone please help me to understand who is right?

Comment: Since a norm is also a seminorm, the classmates are not wrong, but your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a norm. The triangle inequality is just
\begin{align}
(n+s)(x+y)&=n(x+y)+s(x+y) \leq n(x) +s(x) + n(y) + s(y) \\
&= (n+s)(x) + (n+s)(y)
\end{align}
Absolute homogenity is similar and positivity follows directly by the positivity of s and n. It remains to show that $0=(n+s)(x)$ implies $x=0$. But this is just
$0=(n+s)(x)=n(x)+s(x) \geq n(x) \geq 0$ and hence $n(x)=0$ which implies $x=0$ since n is a norm.